# UIToolbar setFrame not working

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uitoolbarposition

I want to toggle visibility of a toolbar at the top of the screen by sliding it out of the visible area. To that end I store the toolbar's y-coordinate and height on viewDidLoad, and update it accordingly when I want it to fade-in/fade-out.

The relevant code snippet looks something like this (you can also find a sample project at https://github.com/Duffycola/test/tree/master/TestHideToolbar):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIToolbar* toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL toolbarVisible;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float toolbarOriginY;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.toolbarVisible = YES;
    self.toolbarOriginY = self.toolbar.frame.origin.y;
}

- (IBAction)handleToggleToolbar:(id)sender;
{
    self.toolbarVisible = !self.toolbarVisible;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        CGRect toolbarFrame = self.toolbar.frame;

        if (self.toolbarVisible)
        {
            toolbarFrame.origin.y = self.toolbarOriginY;
        }
        else
        {
            toolbarFrame.origin.y = self.toolbarOriginY - self.toolbar.frame.size.height;
        }
        self.toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
    }];
}

@end
```

The fade-out works just fine, except when I do anything else on the view. For example when I update a label, the toolbar snaps back to its initial state. I suppose some sort of internal refresh is triggered and the toolbar has an outdated model somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I still had Use Autolayout enabled despite the fact that I thought I had disabled it and removed all constraints before...

Thanks for this: [Frame property of UIView is not getting assigned inside animation on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180969/frame-property-of-uiview-is-not-getting-assigned-inside-animation-on-ios/22183530#22183530)